# Lookup field value has changed after migration to 2019

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, migration, 2019, move

I have moved Sharepoint 2013 subsite to SP 2019 farm. There is one list with "Status" lookup field. All column values has changed for only this field. Values are from same list but different items despite list ids remain same it is showing different lookup value. And i could not find any pattern repeating, or cannot say one ID replaced each other. It seems like just randomly has changed. How can it be possible?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, I understand that the "Status" lookup field values have randomly changed after the site is moved.

Check the lookup field settings. You could create a new lookup field then have a test.

Comment: Hi, there is no issue with the items added newly. Only the old data have this issue. Also list has other lookup fields too, but they are fine. I have corrected the old data by copying from old link but trying to understand how it can be possible while all IDs remain same.